# Small church organization

Tags: cisco, route-server, cisco-small-business, byod

I have just started up my own business in developing networks for small companies and I have my first gig. The gig will be in a small church and it only has one computer but he wants to expand and integrate media cameras inside of the church and he also has 2 other churches that he may consider doing the same thing. My question is, what would be some ideas in expanding this church's network?

I was thinking of building a Remote server to connect the churches data together and for the media cameras to store its data. I was also considering putting a BYOD server in there as well. What are your thoughts?

PS I am also partnered with cisco is there any products that you may suggest?

Comment: Product and resource recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: You should ask your Cisco account manager to get you access to their presales team.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would depend on what they will do with the media from the cameras. Are they using them as security? Or for filming sermons? If it's the second, they'll likely want them on a website for people to view or on DVDs to give out. So, if it is only one church I would say you don't need a remote server, but possibly if it's multiple locations wanting to put the media in one spot to upload to a website or burn to DVDs.

For their network, do they want guest to have WiFi? Most basic small business WiFi routers have built in guest WiFi options as well, which I would imagine the church would want.

More info into what they want will help narrow down a design.